# Is it possible to do a case-insensitive match in a Vim autocmd file pattern without specifying each character as a two-character class?

Tags: vim

I have the following in my `.vimrc` currently to try to activate a custom syntax file.

```
au BufNew,BufRead NOTE,Note setf Note
```

I would like to extend this so that it can match the string `NoTe` for the filename in a case-insensitive manner. The following way is functional but a bit ugly.

```
au BufNew,BufRead [Nn][Oo][Tt][Ee] setf Note
```

**Is there a more explicit way to specify that I want my file pattern to be case insensitive?**

I have already looked at `:help autocmd` and do not see an obvious way, but I am wondering if there is some other option which influences the way that file patterns are parsed, but is not documented there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option: `fileignorecase`, which makes vim handle filename/directories in case insensitive way.

If you set it, you can just use `note` for all cases. However if you set it globally, the filename case will be ignored globally.

For more info about this option: `:h fic`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
au BufNew,BufRead \cnote setf Note
```

to match case insensitively. See https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#pattern-overview for more details of what you can put in patterns.